# Given a set of (x,y) coordinates, give the set of edges to draw a simple polygon

Tags: algorithms, graphs, computational-geometry

Let's say I give you the following array of points:

(1,1) (1,3), (2,2), (4,1), (4,3)

My (terrible) mspaint drawing of the shape that would be created by these looks like this:

[image]

How, given an arbitrary set of coordinates, can I define the edges which constitute a shape with no overlapping edges?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14263284/5376789

Answer (score 1):

A copy from the highest voted answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623817/5376789):

> > Our strategy is to make a plan where we are sure that the polygon
> >     includes all points, and that we can find an order to connect them
> >     where none of the lines intersect.
> >
> > **Algorithm**:
> >
> > 1. Find the leftmost points p
> > 2. Find the rightmost point q
> > 3. Partition the points into A, the set of points below pq, and B, the set of points above pq [you can use the left turn test on (p,q,?)
> >        to
> >        determine if a point is above the line].
> > 4. Sort A by x-coordinate (increasing)
> > 5. Sort B by x-coordinate (decreasing).
> > 6. Return the polygon defined by p, the points in A, in order, q, the points of B in order.
> >
> > **Runtime**:
> >
> > Steps 1,2,3 take O(n) time.
> >     Steps 4,5 take O(nlogn) time.
> >     Step 6 take O(n) time.
> >     Total runtime is O(nlogn).
> >
> > **Correctness**:
> >
> > By construction, all points besides p,q are in set A or
> >     set B. Our output polygon from line 6 therefore outputs a polygon with
> >     all the points. We now need to argue that none of the line segments in
> >     our output polygon intersect each other.
> >
> > Consider each segment in the
> >     output polygon. The first edge from p to the first point in A can't
> >     intersect any segment (because there is no segment yet). As we proceed
> >     in order by x-coordinate through the points in A, from each point, the
> >     next segment is going to the right, and all previous segments are to
> >     the left. Thus, as we go from p, through all the points of A, to point
> >     q, we will have no intersections.
> >
> > The same is true as we go from q back
> >     through the points of B. These segments cannot intersect each other
> >     because they proceed from right to left. These segments also cannot
> >     intersect anything in A because all points in A are below line pq, and
> >     all points in B are above this line.
> >
> > Thus, no segments intersect each
> >     other and we have a simple polygon.
>
> Source: [Broken link](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~pless/546/homeworks/hw1_selectedProblems.pdf)
>
> I understand this is really late, but it might be useful for future
>   viewers.